# UnicodeDecodeError in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a [web page](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AF&ei=LvflU_itN8zbkgW0i4GABQ) using beautifulsoup and used the following code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
  gHeader = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
  gNewsLinkUrl = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AF&ei=LvflU_itN8zbkgW0i4GABQ"
  lPrevLinkReq = urllib2.Request(gNewsLinkUrl,headers=gHeader)
  lPrevPage = urllib2.urlopen(lPrevLinkReq)
  lPrevPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(lPrevPage )
```

When I am executing the above function `parse()` I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_finance_news.py", line 42, in <module>
    FetchNewsDataFromWeb()
  File "google_finance_news.py", line 33, in FetchNewsDataFromWeb
    lPrevPage = BeautifulSoup(lPrevPage)
  File "C:\C42\Finance\bs4\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\C42\Finance\bs4\__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\C42\Finance\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 195, in feed
    self.parser.close()
  File "parser.pxi", line 1283, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:98846)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1313, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:98695)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 142, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:112853)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 130, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:112677)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 327, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:10196)
  File "saxparser.pxi", line 499, in lxml.etree._handleSaxData (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:107747)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 719: invalid continuation byte
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, first, is the page you're downloading actually UTF-8? (Your web browser should have a way to show you this, but a better place to look is to print out the headers from the `urllib2` response object and see what the `content-type` header says.)

Comment: Also, that extra space at the front of the URL makes it invalid. Maybe `urllib2` magically fixes that for you, but I don't know. Have you tried printing out `lPrevLinkReq.read()` to see if it looks like the right page?

Comment: Finally, what do the bytes around position 742 look like?

Comment: the code works as is.